# Replace field with value from other line

Tags: shell, awk

I have the following contents in a file, divided into fields:

```
$ cat list
ldap    12309423409875
account01   98734598073
notes   4736594384325
```

I want to change the value of the second field by taking input from the user which corresponds to first field, using awk. For example, I ask the user to input the field; if he inputs `ldap`, then I should be able to give a different value to the second field of first line.

I tried the following script, but it didn't work:

```
generatepasswd()
{
    date | md5sum
    return
}

cat list
echo "for what do you want to change the password"
pass=`generatepasswd`
read op

awk '$1=="$op"{$2=$pass}1' list > tmp && mv tmp list
```

I get the output if I use the string directly instead of `$op`; for example, if I use `ldap`, I get result, but if I use `$op`, I do not get output. `op` consists of the string `ldap`.

Comment: If any of the following answer helped you in your goal please accept/upvote the answer for closure by ticking right sign besides the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "for what do you want to change the password"
read op
pass=$(date|md5sum)


  awk -v input="$op" -v pass="$pass" '{if($1==input) $2=pass;}1' list
```

This will use bash variables `op` and `pass` inside `awk`.

Comment: [root@oc8210542486 shell]# ./ps
for what do you want to change the password
ldap
./ps: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./ps: line 6: `awk -v input="$op" -v 'pass="$pass" '{if($1==input) {$2=pass;}}1' list'